# Angular, a element has href and onclick, how to prevent the href from redirecting with the onclick?

Tags: html, angular, redirect, angular-router

I have tried e.preventDefault, e.stopPropegation, e.stopImmediatePropegation but none seem to actually prevent the url from being redirected. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: _Not_ using an a if you don't want the click to follow the link?

Comment: Did you try in onClick method "return false"

Comment: Don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you give more details on what the elements purpose is as well as the role of href & onclick.

Answer (score 0):

In short you can do that, this is the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-anqqhw)

```
<a href="/test" (click)="handleClick($event)">Navigate</a>

export class AppComponent {

  handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Test');
  }
}
```